# Airflow SimpleHttpOperator for HTTPS

Tags: https, airflow

I'm trying to use SimpleHttpOperator for consuming a RESTful API. But, As the name suggests, it only supporting HTTP protocol where I need to consume a HTTPS URI. so, now, I have to use either "requests" object from Python or handle the invocation from within the application code. But, It may not be a standard way. so, I'm looking for any other options available to consume HTTPS URI from within Airflow. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using https in the connection? I don't see a requirement for it to be http. But since there is no version provided I could only check against the current code base.

Comment: thanks for the update. i'm using airflow 1.8.0. the connection combo has only shown HTTP option. when making https request against http connection, it returned unauthorised 401 error.

Comment: Could it be that the server you are pulling from is in fact somehow unautorized? Did you try `curl` on the server?

Comment: The `SimpleHTTPOperator` supports the majority of what the `requests` lib supports. If you need to pass in options to the request you can leverage the extra_options below. You can also read more about requests ssl here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-8-stable/airflow/operators/http_operator.py#L42

Comment: Ok, yes. SimpleHttpOperator seems to be supporting both. but, the problem is when creating the http_conn_id where the drop down only shows the list of protocols for HTTP, not HTTPS. the operator is trying to execute the URI with HTTP. For instance, api.xyz.com/v1/abc instead of api.xyz/com/v1/abc. so, the server will throw an unauthorized error when looking at the HTTP request instead of HTTPS.

Comment: I've just tried to select HTTP and then add https in front of the host name.the URI is now created with https://api.xyz.com. let's see how it goes. thanks.

Comment: @Kris did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I've written my own custom solution for this requirement. the SimpleHTTPOperator seems to be ok. but, the drop down to select a protocol when creating a connection only allows to select HTTP. so, the end URI will send a HTTP request rather HTTPS.

Answer (score 7):

I dove into this and am pretty sure that this behavior is a bug in airflow. I have created a ticket for it here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2910

For now, the best you can do is override SimpleHttpOperator as well as HttpHook in order to change the way that HttpHook.get_conn works (to accept https). I may end up doing this, and if I do I'll post some code.

Update:

**Operator override:**

```
from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from operators.https_support.https_hook import HttpsHook


class HttpsOperator(SimpleHttpOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        http = HttpsHook(self.method, http_conn_id=self.http_conn_id)

        self.log.info("Calling HTTP method")

        response = http.run(self.endpoint,
                            self.data,
                            self.headers,
                            self.extra_options)
        if self.response_check:
            if not self.response_check(response):
                raise AirflowException("Response check returned False.")
        if self.xcom_push_flag:
            return response.text
```

**Hook override**

```
from airflow.hooks.http_hook import HttpHook
import requests


class HttpsHook(HttpHook):
    def get_conn(self, headers):
        """
        Returns http session for use with requests. Supports https.
        """
        conn = self.get_connection(self.http_conn_id)
        session = requests.Session()

        if "://" in conn.host:
            self.base_url = conn.host
        elif conn.schema:
            self.base_url = conn.schema + "://" + conn.host
        elif conn.conn_type:  # https support
            self.base_url = conn.conn_type + "://" + conn.host
        else:
            # schema defaults to HTTP
            self.base_url = "http://" + conn.host

        if conn.port:
            self.base_url = self.base_url + ":" + str(conn.port) + "/"
        if conn.login:
            session.auth = (conn.login, conn.password)
        if headers:
            session.headers.update(headers)

        return session
```

**Usage:**

Drop-in replacement for SimpleHttpOperator.

Comment: How to check the response code here when the http api gives something other 200.

Answer (score 5):

This is a couple of months old now, but for what it is worth I did not have any issue with making an HTTPS call on Airflow 1.10.2.

In my initial test I was making a request for templates from sendgrid, so the connection was set up like this:

```
Conn Id   : sendgrid_templates_test
Conn Type : HTTP   
Host      :   https://api.sendgrid.com/
Extra     : { "authorization": "Bearer [my token]"}
```

and then in the dag code:

```
get_templates = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='get_templates',
        method='GET',
        endpoint='/v3/templates',
        http_conn_id = 'sendgrid_templates_test',
        trigger_rule="all_done",
        xcom_push=True
        dag=dag,
    )
```

and that worked.  Also notice that my request happens after a Branch Operator, so I needed to set the trigger rule appropriately (to "all_done" to make sure it fires even when one of the branches is skipped), which has nothing to do with the question, but I just wanted to point it out.

Now to be clear, I did get an Insecure Request warning as I did not have certificate verification enabled.  But you can see the resulting logs below

```
[2019-02-21 16:15:01,333] {http_operator.py:89} INFO - Calling HTTP method
[2019-02-21 16:15:01,336] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-02-21 16:15:01,335] {base_hook.py:83} INFO - Using connection to: id: sendgrid_templates_test. Host:  https://api.sendgrid.com/, Port: None, Schema: None, Login: None, Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: {'authorization': 'Bearer [my token]'}
[2019-02-21 16:15:01,338] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-02-21 16:15:01,337] {http_hook.py:126} INFO - Sending 'GET' to url:  https://api.sendgrid.com//v3/templates
[2019-02-21 16:15:01,956] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - /home/csconnell/.pyenv/versions/airflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
[2019-02-21 16:15:05,242] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-02-21 16:15:05,241] {jobs.py:2527} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I confirm that https is working this way, but were you able to put headers in Extra connection field without overriding HttpHook ? For me this is not working

Comment: in case of a dynamic token ?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem with HTTP/HTTPS when trying to set the connections using environment variables (although it works when i set the connection on the UI).

I've checked the issue **@melchoir55** opened (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2910) and you don't need to make a custom operator for that, the problem is not that HttpHook or HttpOperator can't use HTTPS, the problem is the way get_hook parse the connection string when dealing with HTTP, it actually understand that the first part (http:// or https://) is the connection type.

In summary, you don't need a custom operator, you can just set the connection in your env as the following:

`AIRFLOW_CONN_HTTP_EXAMPLE=http://https%3a%2f%2fexample.com/`

Instead of:

`AIRFLOW_CONN_HTTP_EXAMPLE=https://example.com/`

Or set the connection on the UI.

It is not a intuitive way to set up a connection but I think they are working on a better way to parse connections for Ariflow 2.0.

Comment: This glorious hack is the trick!  We are using AWS Secrets Manager for the connections instead of the Airflow native connections manager, and we have to do this to get https to work.

Answer (score 4):

In Airflow 2.x you can use https URLs by passing `https` for schema value while setting up your connection and can still use `SimpleHttpOperator` like shown below.

```py
    my_api = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id="my_api",
        http_conn_id="YOUR_CONN_ID",
        method="POST",
        endpoint="/base-path/end-point",
        data=get_data,
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Airflow 2.1.0，and the following setting works for https API

- In connection UI, setting host name as usual, no need to specify 'https' in schema field, don't forget to set login account and password if your API server request ones.
  [Connection UI Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfZUk.jpg)
- When constructing your task, add **extra_options** parameter in SimpleHttpOperator, and put your CA_bundle certification file path as the value for key verify, if you don't have a certification file, then use false to skip verification.
  [Task definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlJ1f.jpg)

Reference: [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-8-stable/airflow/operators/http_operator.py#L42)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing HttpsHook, we could just put one line of codes into HttpsOperator(SimpleHttpOperator)@above as follows

```
...

self.extra_options['verify'] = True

response = http.run(self.endpoint,
                        self.data,
                        self.headers,
                        self.extra_options)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

in Airflow 2, the problem is been resolved.
just check out that :

- `host` name in Connection UI Form, don't end up with `/`
- 'endpoint' parameter of `SimpleHttpOperator` starts with `/`