# SSL error in python requests on POST API call

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, airflow

I have to use hit an api request using Airflow. So i was using HttpOperator but facing below error

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<api host>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: <endpoint path> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

So i look at HttpHook code try to replicate it and also wrote my code to hit the api . Below is the sample i wrote

```
import requests



data = {}
data['subject'] = "test mail"
data['fromUserEmail'] = "<sender id>"
data['toUserEmail'] = "<my mail id>"
data['emailContent'] = "test mail"

cookies = "<some headers>"
location = "USA"
content_type = "application/json"
apikey = '<some api key>'
auth = '"Basic <auth key>'

headers = {'X-COM-LOCATION': location, 'Content-Type': content_type, 'apikey': apikey, 'Authorization': auth,
           'Cookie': cookies}
endpoint = "<host> + <path>"

req = requests.Request("POST",url=endpoint,headers=headers,data=data)
ses = requests.Session()
pr = ses.prepare_request(req)
settings = ses.merge_environment_settings(pr.url, {}, None, "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem",None)
pr.body = 'No, I want exactly this as the body.'
resp = ses.send(pr,**settings)
```

but still i am getting same error below is the stack trace

```
>>> pr.body = 'No, I want exactly this as the body.'
>>> resp = ses.send(pr,**settings)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 403, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1053, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 419, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1104, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1375, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<host>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: <path> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<host>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: <path> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))
>>>
>>> print(resp.status_code)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'resp' is not defined
```

I tried many things from stackoverflow and requests' official document but nothing helps me. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: pls take a look at the options suggested here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630344/airflow-simplehttpoperator-for-https
TLDR if you want to try to skip verification use extra_options = {'verify':False}, in your SimpleHttpOperator

Comment: @subram i tried that as well same error